# Ember.js: Best way to get controller in integration test

Tags: ember.js

I have some integration tests which usually look like this:

```
test('can load with available teams', function () {
    visit('/workforce/admin/organizations/create').then(function () {
        var controller = App.__container__.lookup('controller:organizations.create');
        ...
    });
});
```

The underscores in App.__container indicates (for me at least), that this is a private property and should not be accessed externally.

Is there a better way/pattern to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

During testing this is the best way to do it, you can create a test helper so as to avoid having to fix it in multiple places in the event that it changes in the future.

```
// register custom helper
Ember.Test.registerHelper('getController',  
  function(app, controllerName) {
    return app.__container__.lookup('controller:' + controllerName);
  }
);


test('dblClick link increments count', function() {
  expect(2);
  visit('/').then(function(){
    var c = getController('index');
    ok(c.get('good'));
    ok(!c.get('bad'));
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/jesuyeri/14/edit

Comment: Nice. I hadn't seen that way of registering test helpers yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take advantage of ES6 when using @Kingpin2k's answer:

```
Ember.Test.registerHelper('getController',
  (app, controllerName) => app.__container__.lookup('controller:' + controllerName)
);
```